# Using AJAX to insert lat/long into SESSION variables not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps, geolocation

I have a site with a directory of businesses which has links of cities that the user can click and find businesses near that city.

Up until now I have accomplished this simply using a GET variable on the links and processing the location with PHP and Google Maps API.  Unfortunately, the site is starting to generate more than 2500 queries per day so I decided to try using the Javascript API to retrieve the lat/lng client side when the user clicks the link and then set it to the SESSION using AJAX.  I thought I was on the right track but it's not working.  It seems to either not work at all or only change the SESSION variables after clicking on a link several times.  I thought setting `async:false` would fix it, but it didn't

Any Ideas?

Here is my test page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../includes/header.php');

echo $_SESSION["address"] . "<br>";
echo $_SESSION["lat"] . "<br>";
echo $_SESSION["lng"] . "<br>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<a href="test.php" id="Orlando" class="loc">Orlando</a><br /><br />
<a href="test.php" id="Tampa" class="loc">Tampa</a><br /><br />
<a href="test.php" id="Daytona" class="loc">Daytona</a><br /><br />


<script type="text/javascript">
function setLoc(lat,lng,address){
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'setLoc.php',
        data: {lat: lat,lng: lng,address: address}
        });
}

$('.loc').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var address = $(this).attr('id');
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address+'FL'}, function(results, status) {
        var location = results[0].geometry.location;
        lat=location.lat();
        lng=location.lng();
        setLoc(lat,lng,address);
        });
    });
});

</script>

<?php 
require_once('../includes/footer.php');
?>
```

And this is the setLoc.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["address"]);
unset($_SESSION["lat"]);
unset($_SESSION["lng"]);
$_SESSION["lat"] = $_POST["lat"];
$_SESSION["lng"] = $_POST["lng"];
$_SESSION["address"] = $_POST["address"]

?>
```

I added the unsets because I thought clearing it each time would make a difference but it didn't

Comment: First of all, don't ever set async to false, *there be dragons here*. Keep in mind that AJAX is asynchronous, so the SESSION vars will not be set until the AJAX is done. You may want to use [`.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) The `unsets` seem unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction, I ended up using `preventDefault()` and a `success:` function to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my desired result using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setLoc(lat,lng,address,href){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'setLoc.php',
        data: {lat: lat,lng: lng,address: address},
        success: function(){
            location.href=href;
        }
        });
}

$('.loc').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        var href=$(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        var address = $(this).attr('id');
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address+'FL'}, function(results, status) {
        var location = results[0].geometry.location;
        var lat=location.lat();
        var lng=location.lng();
        setLoc(lat,lng,address,href);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```